# JQuery .load() Javascript issue

Tags: jquery, load

I am new to JQuery and I have the following issue:

Source file:

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui )
{
    var draggable = ui.draggable;

    switch (draggable.attr('id'))
    {
        case "artOfBeing":
            alert("Life is a bunch of pointless moments.");
            break;

        case "perfectAndroid":
            $('#dataFrame').load('android/androidConfessions.html #androidData');
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Ajax should load the following file but it only displays `<div id="androidTip">` content and the Javascript is completely ignored! How can I fix this please?

```
<div id="androidData">
    <div id="androidVideo" style="width:640px; height:360px; background-color:#25283c; margin-left:70px; margin-top:0px;">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        FlashReplace.replace("androidVideo", "thoughtOfYou/thought.swf", "flash-element-id", 640, 360, 10);
    </script>

    <div id="androidTip">
        <div><span style="font-weight:bold">"Android"</span> - An alien female incapable of breeding... Even then love gets old and dies.
             <div id="xClose" style="float:right; margin-left:5px; cursor:pointer;">x</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the JS code on your html file will get called when appended to your document. You need to call the JS function from a callback of the load function.

Something like:

```
$('#dataFrame').load('android/androidConfessions.html #androidData', function() {
    FlashReplace.replace("androidVideo", "thoughtOfYou/thought.swf", "flash-element-id", 640, 360, 10);

});
```

Comment: Got it! It is working! Thank you so much. I love callbacks but did not think of it. Must read the JQuery books more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Run the JavaScript as the callback of a successful load instead of trying to push it in with JavaScript. The way you have it now, the JavaScript doesn't ever get executed, just output to the DOM.

Example:

```
$('#result').load('android/androidConfessions.html #androidData', function() {
    FlashReplace.replace("androidVideo", "thoughtOfYou/thought.swf", "flash-element-id", 640, 360, 10);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It was very educational for myself.

Answer (score 0):

When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:

Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will successfully execute.

```
$('#a').load('article.html');
```

However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:

```
$('#b').load('article.html #target');
```